# Find particular solution by method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general form of a particular solution suggested by the method of undetermined coefficients for the DE:

$$ (D^2 + 6D + 10)^2 y = x^3e^{-3x}\sin(x) $$
where $ D = \frac{d}{dx} $

I have solved the characteristic equation of the left side and found the roots to be

$-3+i, -3-i, -3+i, -3-i $

This gives me the complementary function:
$$ y_c(x)=e^{-3x}(C_1\cos(x)+C_2\sin(x))+xe^{-3x}(C_3\cos(x)+C_4\sin(x)) $$

A "rule 2" in my textbook states that if function f(x) is in either of the forms:
$ P_m(x)e^{rx}\sin(kx) $ or $ P_m(x)e^{rx}\cos(kx) $

(where $ P_M*(x) $ is a polynomial of x to the degree of m)
then the particular solution is
$$ x^s((A_0+A_1x+A_2x^2+...+A_mx^m)e^{rx}\cos(kx)+(B_0+B_1x+B_2x^2+...+B_mx^m)e^{rx}\sin(kx)) $$
Where s is the smallest nonnegative integer such that no term in the particular solution
$ y_P $ duplicates a term in the complementary function
$ y_c $

As the right side of my function in in the form specified in rule 2 it think it appllies, meaning i have to check if i have duplication of terms between my general solution and
$ x^3e^{-3x}\sin(x) $
and its derivatives, though this may be incorrect. Assuming that this is the case, how many derivates of $ x^3e^{-3x}\sin(x) $
should i take? Just one? or 4 (as the order of the DE is 4)?
If i dont do any at all then comparing $ x^3e^{-3x}\sin(x) $ to the complementary function i have no duplicate terms and rule 2 gives me the particular solution directly.

Edit: It seems i have misunderstood. I think i should compare the terms of the particular solution in rule 2 and my complementary function
$$ y_c(x)=e^{-3x}(C_1\cos(x)+C_2\sin(x))+xe^{-3x}(C_3\cos(x)+C_4\sin(x)) $$
Doing this i notice that i get duplicate terms
since the terms of my particular solution are $$ e^{-3x}\sin(x),xe^{-3x}\sin(x),x^2e^{-3x}\sin(x),x^3e^{-3x}\sin(x)$$ and the equivalent with $\cos(x)$ instead of $\sin(x)$
Therefore i have to multiply by $x^2$ to avoid duplicates and my particular solution becomes:
$$ x^2((A_0+A_1x+A_2x^2+A_3x^3)e^{-3x}\cos(x)+(B_0+B_1x+B_2x^2+B_3x^3)e^{-3x}\sin(x)) $$
Is this correct?

Comment: Some formatting tips: write `\cos` and `\sin` instead of just `cos` and `sin`, and don't use `*` for multiplication (simply omit it, or write `\times` or `\cdot` instead).

Comment: Okay, i will do that. Thank you :)

Comment: I assume that you meant $(D^2+6D+10)^2$, not $(D+6D+10)^2$, right? Anyway, your edited particular solution looks OK. (But it might be easier if you find a particular solution to the auxiliary complex equation $ (D^2+6D+10)^2 u= x^3 e^{(-3+i)x}$ instead, and then take $y_p=\operatorname{Im} u_p$.)

Comment: Ah yes, ive corrected it now. Thank you for the help :)